# How to allow CORS headers Amazon + Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I am trying to apply watermark to an image retrieved from Amazon s3 on my wordpress website.

I am using this jquery library - http://baivong.github.io/watermark/ where it says that CORS headers have to be enabled.
The watermark works for local images on my website, but not for the ones stored on Amazon S3. As suggested I added to my .htacess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "referer, range, accept-encoding, x-requested-with"
```

and also edited CORS setting on Amazon s3

```
<CORSConfiguration>
<CORSRule>
 <AllowedOrigin>http://mywebsite.com</AllowedOrigin>

<AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
<AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>

<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
```

It is still not working and I was wondering if you can offer any advice on what is not set properly...

Answer (score 1):

This is our CORS Configuration for our bucket. Of course you can add additional Methods

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Origin</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Thanks, I solved it already. Had to replace * with my domain and add crossorgin to the img tag.